# Vim Error for ocaml compiler - E666: compiler not supported: ocaml

Tags: vim, ocaml

I have added this line to my .vimrc:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.ml,*.mli compiler ocaml
```

and when I open a .ml file I get the following error flashed up before it continues to open the file:

```
E666: compiler not supported: ocaml
```

Is my version of vim not compiled with ocmal support? I am using the default vim on Ubuntu 12.04.

Hope someone has some ideas. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would test the compiler command separatedly, `:compiler ocaml`, to check if the problem is some interference with the autocomand.

About the details of your version of Vim, check the output of `:version`. From `:help E666`, you should check for `+eval` on its output.

This error is also displayed if you mistyped the name. The compiler file, when shipped with Vim, should be located on `$VIMRUNTIME`/compiler (use `:echo $VIMRUNTIME` to see the full path).

Comment: The problem was my version. I was using Vim 7.3 which doesn't have support for the ocaml compiler. Upgrading to Vim 7.4 fixed it.

Comment: I'm glad you figured out :)